# How to encrypt existing column data in MySQL database?

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, spring-data-jpa, aes

We are planning to add encryption for few existing columns in database.

Using Spring Data JPA, we are able to encrypt and decrypt the columns data as per the following link:

https://github.com/sunitk/generic-jpa-converter-encrypt-decrypt

But those columns having old data. So we need to encrypt existing column data before using encrypt and decrypt logic above.

Comment: flyway script should be added to encryption on exisiting values.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar can you provide any sample ?

Comment: added answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make a local copy, encrypt the data, update the old unencrypted data with the newly encrypted one.

Comment: @Isabi  How to encrypt the data at mysql database level instead of from java code.  can you provide any sample ?

Comment: I would advice to keep it outside the database, as it should part of the logic of the application.

Anyway, you can update the values as follows: UPDATE table_name SET column_name = MD5(column_name);

There are different hash functions that you can use. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

**aes_encrypt:**
select to_base64(aes_encrypt('1234567812345678', 'this-is-test-key'));
Output: uEFkgLm19vxbMlIVxDnWA+5YofwA1Lqnwcr+rJQ/h/M=

**aes_decrypt:**
select aes_decrypt(from_base64('uEFkgLm19vxbMlIVxDnWA+5YofwA1Lqnwcr+rJQ/h/M='), 'this-is-test-key');
Output: 1234567812345678

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).